# Identity Server 4 create client with IConfiguration

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, identityserver4

I stored my [clients](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/reference/client.html) for my identity server in an appsettings.json file:

```
"ClientSettings":  [
{
  "ClientId": "TestClient1",
  "RedirectUris": [ "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc" ],
  "PostLogoutRedirectUris": [ "http://localhost:5002/signout-callback-oidc" ],
  "AllowedGrantTypes": [ "hybrid" ],
  "AllowedScopes": [ "openid","profile","email" ],
  "RequireConsent": "false",
  "Enabled": "true",
  "ClientSecrets": [
    {
      "Description": "This is the client sceret description.",
      "Value": "password123"
    }
  ]
}
],
```

In my `ConfigureServices` method I setup the dependency injection

```
services.Configure<List<Client>>(config.GetSection("ClientSettings"));
```

My `IClientStore` gets the list of clients via dependency injection. Of course, I need to hash the client secret. To keep this question simple, I wrote this code which assumes I only have a single client with a single client secret.

```
public ClientConfigFileStore(IOptions<List<Client>> options)
{
    var jsonClient = options.Value[0];
    Client client = new Client()
    {
        ClientId = jsonClient.ClientId,
        RedirectUris = jsonClient.RedirectUris,
        PostLogoutRedirectUris = jsonClient.PostLogoutRedirectUris,
        AllowedGrantTypes = jsonClient.AllowedGrantTypes,
        AllowedScopes = jsonClient.AllowedScopes,
        RequireConsent = jsonClient.RequireConsent,
        Enabled = jsonClient.Enabled,
    };//Works
    Client client = jsonClient;//Does not work

    client.ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>()
    {
        new Secret(jsonClient.ClientSecrets.First().Value.Sha256())
    };
    clients = new List<Client>() { client };
}
```

Somehow I need to create a new instance of the `Client` and using the instance created by dependency injection does not work. After the user enters his credentials at the identity server the redirection back to the client fails with `Client secret validation failed for the client: TestClient1`

Why is creating a new instance necessary and is there a more elegant way to load the clients from the `appsettings.json` file?

Comment: why are you loading them from that file?  Why not give it its own file?

Comment: I can do that too and would be more organized. But this does not solve the problem?

Comment: why arent you just using AddInMemoryClients?  I guess i dont understand why you are doing it like this what exactly is it you are trying to do.

Comment: I want an easy way to adjust client settings. When adjusting settings while using the `AddInMemoryClients`, a new version of the identity server need to be published.

Comment: Thats kind of how it works.   I dont think you can on the fly add new clients into in memory.  If you want to be able to add them like that you should have them in a database.   I am going to go dig around in the code an see if there is a way to add in memory clients on the fly.

Comment: Okay, initially I did not want to hardcode the client secret. So I used the appsettings.json file for this purpose. Then I thought, why not move all client specific settings in this (or a separate) file. And now I am curious, why creating a new instance is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure i understand what you are trying to do or why you are trying to do it like this.   Mainly I am not sure why you want to load them in DI like you are. You should look into using in memory clients.

## startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // configure identity server with in-memory stores, keys, clients and scopes
        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients());
    }
```

### config.cs

```
public class Config
{
    // scopes define the API resources in your system
    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
    {
        return new List<ApiResource>
        {
            new ApiResource("api1", "My API")
        };
    }

    // clients want to access resources (aka scopes)
    public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
    {
        // client credentials client
        return new List<Client>
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "client",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,

                ClientSecrets = 
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },
                AllowedScopes = { "api1" }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Code from [quickstart identityserver](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/65e1ad4a6162afc59e810b99910ed4cd10bac9fb/Quickstarts/1_ClientCredentials/src/QuickstartIdentityServer)

Comment: You are right with the in-memory methods. I edited your answers to fit my needs in case other people have similar issues. I prefer loading the clients from the *.json file rather than hard-coding them. This also removes secrets from the code base. Even though I still have no Idea why this conversion (or creating a new instance and copying) works, while the other approach doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Change your client secret part to this:

```
"ClientSecrets": [
      {
        "Value": "<Sha256 hash of secret>",
        "Type": "SharedSecret"
      }
 ],
```